# Need help simplifying a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I would like to make it easier to read, but I can't think of a way to do it. This is what I've got:

```
             timestamp participant participant_name  name handicap sportsbooks.bookie_key odds     bookie prop_id unique_id
1  2024-01-02T05:39:12           1      Joel Embiid  Over     34.5                 Points -116   pinnacle       1       1.1
2  2024-01-02T05:39:12           1      Joel Embiid Under     34.5                 Points -114   pinnacle       1       1.1
3  2024-01-02T07:00:24           1      Joel Embiid  Over     34.5                 Points -120    fanduel       1       1.1
4  2024-01-02T07:00:24           1      Joel Embiid Under     34.5                 Points -106    fanduel       1       1.1
5  2024-01-02T02:35:05           1      Joel Embiid  Over     34.5                 Points -135 draftkings       1       1.1
6  2024-01-02T02:35:05           1      Joel Embiid Under     34.5                 Points  105 draftkings       1       1.1
7  2024-01-02T04:43:05           1      Joel Embiid  Over     52.5                 Points -110 draftkings       1       1.1
8  2024-01-02T04:43:05           1      Joel Embiid Under     52.5                 Points -120 draftkings       1       1.1
9  2024-01-02T07:26:10           1      Joel Embiid  Over     34.5                 Points -120     betmgm       1       1.1
10 2024-01-02T04:42:14           1      Joel Embiid Under     34.5                 Points -115     betmgm       1       1.1
11 2024-01-02T07:26:12           1      Joel Embiid  Over     33.5                 Points -135   barstool       1       1.1
12 2024-01-02T07:26:12           1      Joel Embiid Under     33.5                 Points  105   barstool       1       1.1
13 2024-01-01T23:16:02           1      Joel Embiid  Over     34.5                 Points -115   barstool       1       1.1
14 2024-01-01T23:16:02           1      Joel Embiid Under     34.5                 Points -115   barstool       1       1.1
15 2024-01-02T04:43:07           1      Joel Embiid  Over     35.5                 Points  100   barstool       1       1.1
16 2024-01-02T04:43:07           1      Joel Embiid Under     35.5                 Points -130   barstool       1       1.1
17 2024-01-01T23:40:17           1      Joel Embiid  Over     52.5                 Points -110   barstool       1       1.1
18 2024-01-01T23:40:17           1      Joel Embiid Under     52.5                 Points -120   barstool       1       1.1
```

This is a partially filled in example how I would want this to look:

```
      pinnacle   fanduel draftkings betmgm barstool
33.5      <NA>      <NA>       <NA>     NA     <NA>
34.5 -116/-114 -120/-106   -135/105     NA     <NA>
35.5      <NA>      <NA>       <NA>     NA 100/-130
52.5      <NA>      <NA>  -110/-120     NA     <NA>
```

My end goal is to put the odds ('over odds'/'under odds') in the dataframe if they exist, and leave the rest as NA. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

I'm not really sure where to begin, this question has been stuck on my mind for a few hours.

---

Data:

```r
data = structure(list(timestamp = c("2024-01-02T05:39:12", "2024-01-02T05:39:12", 
                                    "2024-01-02T07:00:24", "2024-01-02T07:00:24", "2024-01-02T02:35:05", 
                                    "2024-01-02T02:35:05", "2024-01-02T04:43:05", "2024-01-02T04:43:05", 
                                    "2024-01-02T07:26:10", "2024-01-02T04:42:14", "2024-01-02T07:26:12", 
                                    "2024-01-02T07:26:12", "2024-01-01T23:16:02", "2024-01-01T23:16:02", 
                                    "2024-01-02T04:43:07", "2024-01-02T04:43:07", "2024-01-01T23:40:17", 
                                    "2024-01-01T23:40:17"), participant = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), participant_name = c("JoelEmbiid", 
                                                                                                                                                  "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", 
                                                                                                                                                  "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", 
                                                                                                                                                  "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid", 
                                                                                                                                                  "JoelEmbiid", "JoelEmbiid"), name = c("Over", "Under", "Over", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "Under", "Over", "Under", "Over", "Under", "Over", "Under", "Over", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "Under", "Over", "Under", "Over", "Under", "Over", "Under"), 
                      handicap = c(34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 52.5, 52.5, 
                                   34.5, 34.5, 33.5, 33.5, 34.5, 34.5, 35.5, 35.5, 52.5, 52.5
                      ), sportsbooks.bookie_key = c("Points", "Points", "Points", 
                                                    "Points", "Points", "Points", "Points", "Points", "Points", 
                                                    "Points", "Points", "Points", "Points", "Points", "Points", 
                                                    "Points", "Points", "Points"), odds = c(-116L, -114L, -120L, 
                                                                                            -106L, -135L, 105L, -110L, -120L, -120L, -115L, -135L, 105L, 
                                                                                            -115L, -115L, 100L, -130L, -110L, -120L), bookie = c("pinnacle", 
                                                                                                                                                 "pinnacle", "fanduel", "fanduel", "draftkings", "draftkings", 
                                                                                                                                                 "draftkings", "draftkings", "betmgm", "betmgm", "barstool", 
                                                                                                                                                 "barstool", "barstool", "barstool", "barstool", "barstool", 
                                                                                                                                                 "barstool", "barstool"), prop_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), unique_id = c(1.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to stay with base R, a possible solution is to `aggregate` and `reshape` the data:

```r
new = 
  with(data, aggregate(x = list(OR = odds), 
                       by = list(handicap = handicap, bookie = bookie), 
                       FUN = \(o) paste(unique(o), collapse = "/"), drop = FALSE)) |>
  reshape(idvar = "handicap", timevar = "bookie",  direction = "wide")
```

gives

```r
> new
  handicap OR.barstool OR.betmgm OR.draftkings OR.fanduel OR.pinnacle
1     33.5    -135/105      <NA>          <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
2     34.5        -115 -120/-115      -135/105  -120/-106   -116/-114
3     35.5    100/-130      <NA>          <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
4     52.5   -110/-120      <NA>     -110/-120       <NA>        <NA>
```

It is generally not recommend to move a column to row names.

```r
colnames(new) = gsub("OR.", "", colnames(new))
rownames(new) = new$handicap
new$handicap = NULL
```

then

```r
> new
      barstool    betmgm draftkings   fanduel  pinnacle
33.5  -135/105      <NA>       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
34.5      -115 -120/-115   -135/105 -120/-106 -116/-114
35.5  100/-130      <NA>       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
52.5 -110/-120      <NA>  -110/-120      <NA>      <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created your dataframe with necessary columns

```
aa <- data.frame(handicap = c(34.5, 34.5,34.5,34.5, 34.5,34.5, 52.2),
                 odds = c(-116, 114, 120, 106, 135, 105, -110), 
                 bookie = c("pinnacle", "pinnacle", "fanduel", "fanduel", "draftkings", "draftkings", "draftkings"))
```

Firstly I grouped by and pasted values for odds according to bookie and handicap, to get unique values, and final step to make pivot wider to get column name from bookie column and adding values from odds

```
aa %>% 
  group_by(bookie,handicap) %>% 
  summarize(odds = paste(unique(odds), collapse = " / ")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "bookie", values_from = c(odds))
```

output:

[image]

Comment: if I missed something please let me know

Comment: `tibble::column_to_rownames("handicap")` function doesnt work, are you sure, it is still available function?

Comment: `Error: 'columns_to_rownames' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tibble'`, yes documentation could keep arc file, but I am not sure for it is available for new version of package